# Removing Duplicated Substrings

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-update, concatenation

I understand that the following question may not be best practice.

I have a table that has the following structure, the keyword column and title column concat into the mashup column.

```
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Keyword    | Title      | Mashup                |
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Green      | Green      | Green Green           |
| Green      | Watermelon | Green Watermelon      |
| Watermelon | Watermelon | Watermelon Watermelon |
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to know if there is a way of "deduping" the string. So my table will look more like the below:

```
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Keyword    | Title      | Mashup                |
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| Green      | Green      | Green                 |
| Green      | Watermelon | Green Watermelon      |
| Watermelon | Watermelon | Watermelon            |
+------------+------------+-----------------------+
```

Is this possible? I can't seem to find a solution. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| Keyword    | Title      | Another     | Mashup                      |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
| Green      | Green      | Pink        | Green Green Pink            |
| Green      | Watermelon | Yellow      | Green Watermelon Yellow     |
| Watermelon | Watermelon | Black       | Watermelon Watermelon Black |
+------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET Mashup = IF(Keyword = Title, Keyword, CONCAT(Keyword, ' ', Title));
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02713/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
|    KEYWORD |      TITLE |           MASHUP |
|------------|------------|------------------|
|      Green |      Green |            Green |
|      Green | Watermelon | Green Watermelon |
| Watermelon | Watermelon |       Watermelon |
```

Comment: Thank a lot for that! I think I partially understand what you have done here. I edited my question with another example with an extra column what would be done if there are multiple columns?

Comment: Also would this be done before the data is entered into the column? and would it automatically update from then on?

Comment: Okay thank you! Also could you help me understand what would happen if this needed to be done across more columns like in my edited question. Thanks for your time

Comment: Correct but the way i understood the IF statment was that if Keyword = title, but adding another column like "another" it would not check if keyword = another? Am I wrong? Thanks