# MySQL Dedupe column so no word appears more than once

Tags: mysql

I asked a question here but I feel I was not descriptive enough, for what I asked I got the answer but what I was looking for is a little more in-depth.

[Removing Duplicated Substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964397/removing-duplicated-substrings)

What I currently have is a table like the below. The mashup column is a concat of the other columns, I am trying to basically dedupe that column so that 1 word appears only once. This is because I will be querying this column, I understand is it not best practice but it works best for what I need.

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| Keyword     | Title      | URL         | production | Mashup                            |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| Green       | Green      | Pink        | Green      | Green Green Pink Green            |
| Green       | Watermelon | Yellow      | Sweet      | Green Watermelon Yellow Sweet     |
| Watermelon  | Watermelon | Black       | Cream      | Watermelon Watermelon Black Cream |
| Green Green | Green      | Watermelon  | Sweet      | Green Green Green Watermelon Sweet|
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

This is what I am trying to achive:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| Keyword     | Title      | URL         | production | Mashup                            |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| Green       | Green      | Pink        | Green      | Green Pink                        |
| Green       | Watermelon | Yellow      | Sweet      | Green Watermelon Yellow Sweet     |
| Watermelon  | Watermelon | Black       | Cream      | Watermelon Black Cream            |
| Green Green | Green      | Watermelon  | Sweet      | Green Watermelon Sweet            |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
```

As you can see in the table I wish to be left with the mashup column doesn't have Green mentioned twice or any other word. The answer to my previous question would work on row 1,2 and 3 but it will not work on row 4 as it has green in the keyword column twice.

Is there anyway around this, I am at a total dead end and cannot find a way around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of the `Mashup` column. Why duplicate data from the other columns? Why remove duplicate words? How are you populating this column? Can the duplicates be avoided there? Explaining this will help us provide the proper solution.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I am basically making a sort of search engine, the crawler will populate the fields accordingly Title, Keywords etc. The problem is when querying the database for something like "Green Watermelon" you would expect something that includes both works to rank first. BUT what is ranking in first position is somthing that has say "Green Green" in the Title column and "Green" in the keywords column. This apparently has a much higher relevancy than somthing that has "Green Watermelon" in Title or even "Green" in title and "watermelon" in keywords. So the results are way off.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Therefore I decided if it was possible to create a column that de duped everything and had the keywords in I could query that column and get a better result set. As Because it is seeing "Green" 3 times it is rewarding it more than somthing that says "Green Watermelon" as that only has 2 of the search words in.

Comment: Does your search use [FULLTEXT BOOLEAN searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)?

Comment: @MarcusAdams FULLTEXT yes BOOLEAN no. Reason being, although this will work, it is exact match so it will only show results that have Green AND Wartermelon in. I would like those results to be prioritised as having more relevancy I would still like the Stuff with "Green Green Green" only in the title to rank just lower than the more relevant such as the "Green Watermelon"

Comment: Should be working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/440b34/1/0

Comment: @MarcusAdams Can I add you on Skype? This doesn't seem to work for me. SEOstyx is skype